# Two way ANOVA - repeated measure in r, missing a desired effect

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to do a two way mixed factorial ANOVA with repeated measures. From:

```
aov(Estimate ~ Dose*Visit, data = AUClast)
```

I get 3 sums of squares: two main effects (Visit and Dose) and their interaction (Dose:Visit) which I figured out by hand are correct.

Both Dose and Visit are explanatory variables with Dose being a between subject variable with 4 levels, 3, 10, 30, 100 and Visit being a within subjects variable (repeated measure) of 2 levels, 1 and 28. Also, the subjectID variable is 'Animal'

I want to include one more effect into the result but do not know how. The desired effect is variance between Animal within Dose, or how SAS puts it Animal(Dose). The SS is calculated by:

```
sum((mean(Animal(ik))-mean(Dose(i))^2)
```

Where k is the animal of a dose i (averaging the Estimates of the observation in Visit 1 and Visit 28 for each Animal and subtracting the mean Estimate of animals in that Dose quantity squared for all Animals in this study).

Does anyone know how to adjust the formula accordingly to include the Animal(Dose) effect?

Thanks in advance for the help and sorry if all of this is too unspecific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I have a suggestion. First, a sample data set

```
#sample data
set.seed(15)
AUClast<-data.frame(
    expand.grid(
    Animal=1:3,
    Dose=c(3,10,30,100),
    Visit=c(1,28)
    ), Estimate=runif(24)
)
```

Now we calculate the interaction term as requested. First, we split the data into dosage groups, then for each does, we subtract the overall mean from the mean for each animal. Then we sum the squared of those differences. Finally, we expand them back out to does group using `unsplit`.

```
animaldose<-unsplit(lapply(split(AUClast, AUClast$Dose), function(x) {
    rep(
        sum((tapply(x$Estimate, x$Animal, mean) - mean(x$Estimate))^2)
    , nrow(x))
}), AUClast$Dose)
```

And we can see what that looks like next to the original data.frame

```
cbind(AUClast, animaldose)
```

Which gives the result

```
   Animal Dose Visit   Estimate animaldose
1       1    3     1 0.60211404  0.1181935
2       2    3     1 0.19504393  0.1181935
3       3    3     1 0.96645873  0.1181935
4       1   10     1 0.65090553  0.1641363
5       2   10     1 0.36707189  0.1641363
6       3   10     1 0.98885921  0.1641363
7       1   30     1 0.81519341  0.0419291
8       2   30     1 0.25396837  0.0419291
9       3   30     1 0.68723085  0.0419291
10      1  100     1 0.83142902  0.1881314
11      2  100     1 0.10466936  0.1881314
12      3  100     1 0.64615091  0.1881314
13      1    3    28 0.50909039  0.1181935
14      2    3    28 0.70662857  0.1181935
15      3    3    28 0.86231366  0.1181935
16      1   10    28 0.84178515  0.1641363
17      2   10    28 0.44744372  0.1641363
18      3   10    28 0.96466695  0.1641363
19      1   30    28 0.14118707  0.0419291
20      2   30    28 0.77671251  0.0419291
21      3   30    28 0.80372740  0.0419291
22      1  100    28 0.79334595  0.1881314
23      2  100    28 0.35756312  0.1881314
24      3  100    28 0.05800106  0.1881314
```

So you can see each does group has it's own adjustment.

Comment: This is a good start, but the dose is not a repeated measure. So Each animal is only receiving one fixed dose meaning in your model there would have to be 12 total subjects, three in each dose group. The animaldose part is good. I just need that all translated into an aov output somehow.

Comment: @sugarfacex101 Well, it would have been helpful if you had supplied sample data. I'm still not sure I understand what the problem is. Perhaps you could edit your question to make it more clear. Don't you plan to use this as `aov` input?

Comment: Yes that is my intention. the data you generated is actually quite accurate aside from the the number of Animals,I will post some data.

Comment: @sugarfacex101 I'm not sure I see how your real data would change the way I answer the question. Am I missing something? Is that not the calculation you asked for?

Comment: It is close enough so I will give it to you. Its a platform for me to start off from, thanks for your help.